# Is there an event that is triggered when a component is no longer displayed on the screen?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3

I have a custom component I've developed that's part of a dashboard.

It does some polling based on a timer that's part of the component.

When the user navigates away from the view that contains this component I would like to stop the timer and hence stop the polling.

I can obviously fire an event when the view's changed and catch it within the component but I was hoping that there might be a way to contain this all within the component.

Is there an event or state change within a component that triggers and even when a component is currently be displayed?

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions!

Example:

```
        ]]>
        </mx:Script>

        <mx:TabBar x="10" y="10" dataProvider="viewstack1">
        </mx:TabBar>

        <mx:ViewStack x="0" y="0" id="viewstack1" width="675" height="315">
                <mx:Canvas label="View 1" width="100%" height="100%">
                        <mx:Button x="74" y="69" label="Button 1" width="429" height="185" removedFromStage="removeFromStageEvent()"/>
                </mx:Canvas>
                <mx:Canvas label="View 2" width="100%" height="100%">
                        <mx:Button x="74" y="69" label="Button 2" width="429" height="185" color="red"/>
                </mx:Canvas>        
        </mx:ViewStack>

</mx:Application>
```

Comment: Which component being displayed determines whether or not the timer should be running? Are you trying to figure out if the user has switched views in your `ViewStack`?

Comment: I updated my answer with an example of detecting when a users switches between views in a `ViewStack`. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I have the same thing with ViewStack components and the removedFromStage problem, its a tricky mofo!

Answer (score 3):

`removedFromStage` is triggered when a component is about to be removed from the stage.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2#REMOVED_FROM_STAGE

> Dispatched when a display object is about to be removed from the display list, either directly or through the removal of a sub tree in which the display object is contained. Two methods of the DisplayObjectContainer class generate this event: removeChild() and removeChildAt().

Comment: Samuel & Jason - thanks for trying to help out on this one.  I'm attaching a simple example in which I'm trying to see if a button is no longer showing and I tried the removedFromStage event but in this case I'm wondering if due to the ViewStack, the button is always considered "on the stage"  In my real app, the custom component is contained within a hierarchy like this and sometimes just within a panel.  See updated description for sample app.

Comment: @fortpointuiguy, in this case why don't you want to just put a `change` handler on the `ViewStack` itself?

Comment: Samuel - thanks again and yes, I can put a change handler on the ViewStack itself as you've described.  My worry was that there will be cases in which my custom component is displayed in other views (other than a viewstack) and I was hoping the custom component could pick up on the fact of whether it was currently showing or not all on its own.

Comment: @fortpointuiguy, unfortunately to do that reliably you need to both listen to the `removedFromStage` event for the component itself and also the `hide` event for your component and all of it's parents.  There's the added complication that a component can be reparented at which point you need to recalculate which components to listen to the `hide` event for and I'm not sure what events are broadcasted when a component is reparented, perhaps `removedFromStage` and `addedToStage` but I'm not certain.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
If you're trying to determine when the user switches between `View 1` and `View 2` in your `ViewStack`, you could add an event listener to the `viewstack1`'s `change` event.

```
<fx:Script>
  <![CDATA[

    protected function viewstack1_changeHandler(event:IndexChangedEvent):void
    {
      // Do Something
    }

  ]]>
</fx:Script>

<mx:TabBar x="10" y="10" dataProvider="viewstack1" />

<mx:ViewStack x="0" y="0" id="viewstack1" width="675" height="315" change="viewstack1_changeHandler(event);">
  <mx:Canvas label="View 1" width="100%" height="100%">
    <mx:Button x="74" y="69" label="Button 1" width="429" height="185" />
  </mx:Canvas>
  <mx:Canvas label="View 2" width="100%" height="100%">
    <mx:Button x="74" y="69" label="Button 2" width="429" height="185" color="red"/>
  </mx:Canvas>        
</mx:ViewStack>
```

If you're using the `visible` property of your component to determine if it's displayed or not, you can also use the `hide` event handler in your component.

```
<local:MyComponent hide="hideHandler(event)">
  <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

    protected function hideHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
    {
      // Do something here.
    }

    ]]>
  </fx:Script>
</local:MyComponent>
```

Comment: This will only work if the component itself is hidden directly.  If it hidden indirectly (i.e., it's parent or grandparent or great-grandparent gets hidden) then this even will not fire.

Comment: @Samuel Neff, Good point. This will only work if used on a top level component. Question though: If you toggle visibility using `visible=false` does the `removedFromStage` event get fired?

Comment: no, `removedFromStage` does not get fired when visibility is toggled.  There is no perfect solution to this problem.  It depends on the architecture and what your app does when changing states and moving between views.  Generally adding/removing from stage is recommended over toggling visibility since adding/removing from stage uses less memory and improves performance.

Comment: @Samuel Neff, Agreed. I just posted the visibility answer in case that was how the original poster was managing whether the components were visible or not. Good to know about the `removedFromStage` bit though. Learn something new every day. :)

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use the [focus events](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/FocusEvent.html) in combination with a hit test of an invisible sprite that covers the whole stage and/or the view/component visiblity (may need a chain of these).